# Beautifulsoup navigating divs by attribute without findAll

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How do I find a specific div by calling the attributes of a soup? i.e. something like `soup.html.body.div` however I don't see how to get the specific div with `id='idname'` here?

I can do `soup.findAll(id='idname')[0]` to get the specific tag, but as I understand it this is searching the whole soup.

I imagine getting the div by attribute on the soup would be faster since you are not using `findAll()`?

Firebug reports the location as being `html.body.div[2].form.table[2].tbody.tr[3]...` however doing `soup.html.body.div[2]` gives a key error.

**Update:**

Say you want to grab the **I'm feeling lucky** button from http://www.google.com, firebug reports that as being:

`/html/body/center/span/center/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[2]`

Is there a way to reach this *without* using `findAll`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path you get from Firebug is an XPath expression. It's best to use a parser that lets you use xpath directly. I like using `lxml` with its `etree` interface:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(yourfile)
lucky = tree.xpath('/html/body/center/span/center/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[2]')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `findChildren` method which gets most of the way there.

It's equivalent to:

```
findAll(tagname, recursive=False)
```

which will usually make it much more efficient.

So your example would become:

```
soup.html.body.center.span.center.findChildren('div')[2].\
    form.findChildren('div')[2].findChildren('div')[3].\
    center.findChildren('input')[2]
```